# MYSQL - Update/Replace wp_usermeta - filtered by other tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

it's my first time on Stackoverflow and just getting my feet wet in MYSQL!  I have a question...

In PHPMYADMIN, I'm trying to update/replace usermeta from one wordpress site to another.  In database DB#1, I want to find all wp_users registered before 10/01/2017 with a specific group ID in wp_bp_groups_members, and then export all their usermeta to CSV.  Then I want to do the same find of these same users in DB#2, delete their usermeta and import the new usermeta from DB#1.

```
SELECT umeta_id
     , m.user_id
     , meta_key
     , meta_value
     , g.group_id
  FROM wp_usermeta m
  JOIN wp_users u
    ON m.user_id = u.ID
  JOIN wp_bp_groups_members g
    ON u.ID = g.user_id
 WHERE g.group_id = 501223 
   AND user_registered < '2017-10-01 00:00:00'
```

When I run this query, I cannot select the records (for delete in DB#2), and get the following message: "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks Strawberry!  I read this article, do I need to provide a data set as well?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?